# Is it possible to create a bootable image of the current system and use it repair my system later?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, backup

I am trying to create a "rescue USB" of sorts. The plan is to back up (or clone) a current image of system (including all the packages and software that I have installed) on a 16 GB or a 32 GB USB stick as a bootable image. Later,if something were to go wrong with my system, I could use that USB to "restore" my system to it's previous state OR install it anew (maybe on a different device) but with my settings intact (this includes the root passwords, apps, additional drivers etc.).

Is there any way to do this in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Note: Remastersys no longer works.

Comment: You could use Clonezilla or similar. http://clonezilla.org/

Comment: I don't think clonezilla cna create a bootable image.

Comment: ...and why would you want it bootable in the first place?

Comment: It would be good if I could it as a Live CD as well. And if my system were to crash completely, how will I recover it if it were not bootable?

Comment: Making backups bootable adds an unneeded layer of complexity. Clonezilla can both make whole system backups and restore from them, so, if a system "completely crashes", you'd boot Clonezilla, and tell it to restore. There are other tools like that: [FSArchiver](http://www.fsarchiver.org/), [TAR backup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR).

Comment: @mikewhatever I think your last comment counts as an answer here...